# Static members initialization works differently on one specific environment in debug and release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static, eigen

I am using C++ 14. And I have some static class members. PseudoCode:

```
Class Zoo
{
      Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> _matrix;

      Zoo()
      {
        _matrix.resize(6, 6)
      }
}

Class Foo
{
   static Zoo _member;
}
```

I should say that I have a lot of unit test with good coverage. This code is compiled and works fine in one env in release and debug(x64). VS 2016. And on other env(also compiled there with VS 2016) it works in debug mode and in the release I got  **Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF** at `_matrix.resize(6, 6)` during initialization. In another case, I got heap corruption also during initialization in other place also during initialization.
I have rebuilt solution several times, manually cleaned VS build folders, have tried MS and Intel compiler, restarted windows :) I can't understand how it is possible that the same code is working in debug and not in release, and works in the release on the other env. How does this can affect static members initialization? I can't debug normally because of release mode.  I should say that I am using Eigen lib in my project, I think this can happens because Eigen is using vectorization and compiler Intrinsics in release mode, and potentially it can be compiled to different instructions set on different envs, but still don't understand how this can affect static members initialization.
*This behavior is reproduced constantly, not from time to time.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried defining the static member? Like so, 'Zoo Foo::_member'?

Comment: @linuxfever yes, no errors in this case.

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve] and not non-working pseudo code -- the root of your problem may actually be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have found "reason" and workaround but technically I don't see any sense this:

I have one more static class StreamReader with several static functions that are deserializing values from the ifstream and no any field:

```
StreamReader
{
    static int ReadInt(ifstream& in);
}

int StreamReader::ReadInt(ifstream& in)
{
     int curInt;
     in.read((char*)(&curInt), sizeof(int));
     return curInt;
}
```

I have called:

```
ifstream in(_dataPath, ios::in | std::ios::binary);
int cols = StreamReader::ReadInt(in);
int rows = StreamReader::ReadInt(in);
```

before the:

```
_matrix.resize(cols, rows).
```

I have removed static keyword from the ReadInt().And changed code to

```
ifstream in(_dataPath, ios::in | std::ios::binary);
StreamReader ser;
int cols = ser.ReadInt(in);
int rows = ser.ReadInt(in);
```

and now all works both in debug and release. Some nonsense. Don't know why this helped, but I have made one conclusion: avoid using statics.